# send URL parameters to Express with Angular 2

Tags: express, angular, url-parameters

I'm using this Angular service to get data from Express:

```
getRestaurants(districtId) : Observable<void[]>{
  let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('id', districtId);

  return this.http.get(this.url, { search: params })
  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

I was using this URL `http://localhost:5050/api/district/restaurants?id=8`

It works fine if in Express I use `req.query` But I need to use this new URL `http://localhost:5050/api/district/:id/restaurants` and use `req.params` in Express.

My problem is that I can't set the `:id` parameter using Angular without modifying the URL string and I suppose that there is a better way to do this task. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```js
private url = 'http://localhost:5050/api/district/:id/restaurants';

private _prepareUrl(districtId: number): string {
   return this.url.replace(':id', districtId);
}

getRestaurants(districtId) {
   // ...

   this.http.get(this._prepareUrl(districtId), ...);

   // ...
}
```

You could use the `Router`'s function `createUrlTree`, but you will have a prepare-function too..

```js
private urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:5050/api';

constructor(private _router: Router) { }

private _prepareUrl(districtId: number): string {
   return this.urlPrefix + this._router.createUrlTree(['district', districtId, 'restaurants']).toString();
}

getRestaurants(districtId) {
   // ...

   this.http.get(this._prepareUrl(districtId), ...);

   // ...
}
```